# How do I download the network library for processing?

Tags: processing

I've tried downloading it by going into the import library sub-menu and selecting add library however the network library doesn't come up. I then went on [this GitHub link](https://github.com/processing/processing) and clicked "Download ZIP" but chrome blocked the download.

Comment: If the project is too big, you need to use git to download it or else it won't work, kinda like you just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the library [ships with Processing](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/java/libraries/net).

To test:

1. go to **Processing > Examples > Libraries > Network**
2. Open and run **SharedCanvasServer**
3. Open and run **SharedCanvasClient** and start drawing

That should demonstrate the library is installed and running.
Use the [Network library reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/) to write your own basic TCP Server/Client for your needs.

If you need a UDP server it's worth installing/trying [oscP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/) (which can be installed via the **Contribution Manager**)